# Springfox @RestController naming

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I'm getting some minor troubles using Springfox. I can't set a name to @RestController classes.

I'm using Spring boot and Swagger2.

The following code will produce a controller named "rest-status-controller" in springfox ui. I've expected a "Application Status" instead. Is there another config I'm not aware of ?

```
@Api("Application Status")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/status")
public class RestStatusController {

    @ApiOperation(value="Get components current status")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String global() {
    //...
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Get mysql current status")
    @RequestMapping(value="/mysql" method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String mysql() {
    //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try to use the `tags` parameter of the `@Api` Annotation to change the name of the grouping of your RestController methods. Excerpt from the corresponding Java Doc (shortened):

```
/**
 * A list of tags for API documentation control.
 * Tags can be used for logical grouping of operations by resources or any other qualifier.
 */
String[] tags() default "";
```

In your case, just use:

```
@Api(tags = "Application Status")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/status")
public class RestStatusController {
    ...
}
```

This should group all documented operations from `RestStatusController` with the tag "Application Status".

Comment: This issue needs its own name.

Answer (score 9):

Use both tags and description to avoid controller name API grouping. For example:

```
@Api(
  tags="Application Status.",
  description = "Provides Application Status API's.
")
```

Answer (score 6):

`@Tags(name = "name", description = "description")`
As per OpenApi v3

Answer (score 5):

For OpenApi v3:

```
@Tag(name = "name")
```